# Learning how the Reduce function works in JavaScript by creating one from scratch

Tags: javascript

This seems to work well when passing a simple add function:

```
var add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};

function reduce(arr, startingValue, func) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
        var result = 0,
            l = arr.length,
            i = 0;
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            result += func(arr[i], startingValue);
        }
        return result;
    }
    return false;
}


reduce([3, 5, 7], 0, add) // returns 15
```

But when I try to pass a function which counts words in an array...

```
function countWordsInReduce(arr, result) {
    var l = arr.length,
        i = 0,
        j = 0,
        index = arr[i],
        newarr = [];

    for (; i < l; i++) {
        index = arr[i].split(' ');
        newarr.push(index)
    }

    function helper(arr) {
        var count = 0;

        arr.forEach(function(cv) {
            if (Array.isArray(cv)) {
                helper(cv);
            } else {
                count++;
            }

        });

        return count;

    }

    for (; j < newarr.length; j++) {
        result += helper(newarr[j])
    }

    return result;

}

var wordArray = ["hello there this is line 1", "and this is line 2"];
reduce(wordArray, 0, countWordsInReduce) // I get 53
```

Funny though when I use the `countWordsInReduce` on its own, it works...

```
countWordsInReduce(wordArray, 0) //returns 11
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: In the `add` function, `b` is always `0`, then it looks like working, but the function `add` has no effect, it is just returning `a`. What's the real purpose of `func`? Why not use the native `Array.reduce`?

Comment: Your `reduce()` doesn't work the same way as `Array.prototype.reduce`: `reduce([3, 5, 7], 5, add) !== [3, 5, 7].reduce(add, 5)` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suz2b91y/))

Comment: Your reduce is doing countWordsInReduce(wordArray[0], 0) + countWordsInReduce(wordArray[1], 0) which is indeed 53

Comment: If you are trying to code a polyfill, [MDN provides one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=control#Polyfill).

Comment: The function passed to `reduce` should take the "accumulator" (the "running value"), the current element of the array on which it is acting, the index of that element in the array, and the array itself. The function should return the new value for the "accumulator", based on the current element in the array (and/or the other parameters). The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) details the procedure pretty well...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks for your help. Just trying to wrap my head around why when I pass `countWordsInReduce` into my reduce i get 53....

Comment: I said why that happens

Comment: In the future, it's better to highlight, in text, not code, where the problem is. In this question, I really had to search for where this 53 was coming from, and finally found it in a comment in a code block. Read [ask] (and the linked articles) for some good advice on writing clear questions.